# Identifier "hport" is undefined

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have been trying to learn how to read or write on a com port on my computer (specifically com11). I have a small understanding of c++, but I have only ever written code for Arduino, so what I was trying to do was new to me. I couldn't find any tutorials or explanations that made sense to me, but I found some code [here](http://members.ee.net/brey/Serial.pdf).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atlstr.h>
using namespace std;

bool WriteComPort(CString PortSpecifier, CString data) {
    DCB dcb;
    DWORD byteswritten;

    HANDLE hport = CreateFile(

        PortSpecifier,
        GENERIC_WRITE,
        0,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        0,
        NULL
    );

    if (!GetCommState(hPort, &dcb))
        return false;

    dcb.BaudRate = CBR_9600;   //9600 Baud
    dcb.ByteSize = 8;          //8 data bits
    dcb.Parity = NOPARITY;     //no parity
    dcb.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT; //1 stop

    if (!SetCommState(hPort, &dcb))
        return false;

    bool retVal = WriteFile(hPort, data, 1, &byteswritten, NULL);
    CloseHandle(hPort);        //close the handle
    return retVal;
}
```

I first encounter a problem here: `if (!GetCommState(hPort, &dcb))` with the error being `Identifier "hport" is undefined`. Every time I use the variable hPort, it gives me a similar error: `'hPort' undeclared identifier.`
Am I using `HANDLE` wrong or is there some other problem I don't know about?

Comment: `hPort` and `hport` are different...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> HANDLE hport = CreateFile

Here, you are defining `hport`, but you are using `hPort`.

> if (!GetCommState(hPort, &dcb))